# Cast from Variant String to Double ignores decimal point

Tags: delphi, variant, decimal-point

I have a few simple lines of code:

```
var
  vRecordValue:Double;
begin
  vRecordValue:= someVariant;
```

Where someVariant is a string (type 256).

On a production system we have a variant of '23.4' and vRecordValue becomes 234. I can only reproduce this is my system separator is ','. In our production system this was the case but we have changed the setting and still see this occurring. It is interesting to note that we cannot reproduce this at all except in debug mode (no idea what the relationship is here), and by doing a simple test.

I fixed this with an explicit conversion:

```
vRecordValue:= StrToFloatDef(VarToStrDef(someVariant, '0'), 0);
```

Questions:

1. Is there any other way that a decimal point could be being ignored?
2. Can someone please provide a reference for how the default cast from string to double is performed? I want to understand the difference.
3. Is there any way that the separator used in the default cast is being cached from the value when the code was first run? ... Doubtful but desperate to understand.

Thanks,

Wayne.

Comment: Did you check your locale settings? I would not rely on a particular locale setting in such cases, instead using a fixed (english) locale for such tasks seems appropriate-

Comment: Thanks. Sorry. I should have been clearer. When I say that the separator is a comma, this is coming from the locale settings. Our production system was in Albania which is why I think we ran into this.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @wayju: I should have placed a bet. That was exactly the case I had in mind.

Comment: @David. Thanks. I can fix the problem by doing an explicit conversion as per my second line of code. From what I understand and what everyone said also I should be able to fix the problem by changing the locale settings. Unfortunately changing the settings to use a decimal separator of '.' and a thousands separator of ',' didn't make the problem go away. I am hoping someone can help me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is your regional settings

I've made this samall demo applikation inorder for testing it:

```
procedure TForm60.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  vRecordValue: Double;
  sRecordValue: Variant;
begin
  sRecordValue:= '23.4';
  vRecordValue:= StrToFloatDef(VarToStrDef(sRecordValue, '0'), 0);
  ShowMessage(FloatToStr(vRecordValue));

  sRecordValue:= '23,4';
  vRecordValue:= StrToFloatDef(VarToStrDef(sRecordValue, '0'), 0);
  ShowMessage(FloatToStr(vRecordValue));
end;
```

In Denmark (Where I live) the we use , as decimal seperator, so the last one gives me the correct result

Comment: Thanks Jens. I did a similar test and found the same problem. But what I don't understand is why after modifying our system configuration (changing it from comma to dot), then the problem didn't go away. Is there anything else that you can think of that would cause this issue? Or could the configuration be cached in some way? We have restarted the server.

Comment: I have to accept this answer in terms of why the problem occurs. This is what I also found in my testing, but didn't match the apparent configuration of our production servers.

We released a patch with the explicit conversion mentioned in my initial question and it appears to work in our production servers. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: My post below explains why changing the settings didn't work... because we weren't changing it for the user running the service!

Answer (score 1):

In regards to my third question. The problem reoccurred this week. I didn't realize that the locale/regional settings are only being set for the current user.

To copy the settings for system users, we needed to use:

Control Panel > Region and Language > Administrative > Copy Settings.

This is why I had inconsistencies when testing. It depended on the user my application was running as, and that users settings.